# Show that there is no subgroup B of $\mathbb Z ^2$ such that $\mathbb Z ^2 / B \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_{21}$

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I have the following question in group theory:

> Show that there is no subgroup $B$ of $\mathbb Z ^2$ such that $\mathbb Z ^2 / B \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_{21}$

I don't really know how to approach this question. I thought maybe looking at the generators on the left side, using the first isomorphism theorem, or looking at the prime decomposition, but I'm not really sure. 
I could use a hint in this one. Group theory is not my strongest subject.

Comment: $Z^2$, and therefore also $Z^2/B$, is a $2$-generator group, but the direct product requires $3$ generators.

Answer (score 2):

Any group isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Z}^2/B$ is commutative, and can be generated by two elements, namely the classes of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Actually, this is an exact characterization: if $A$ is an abelian group generated by two elements $x$ and $y$, then we can define a surjective group morphism $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\to A$ by $f(1,0)=x$ and $f(0,1)=y$, and then if $B:= \ker(f)$, this gives $A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2/B$.

Now obviously $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_{21}$ is commutative, so can it be generated by two elements?

Comment: perhaps it is because $gcd(3,6) \neq 1 $, so we cant describe $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_6$ as a group $\mathbb Z_{nm}$. with the same argument, we can say that it's only generated by 3 elements?

Comment: However, your argument seems valid only when $B = ker(f)$, but the question asks to show that there isn't such a subgroup $B$, so maybe we can have a subgroup $B$ that is not the kernel.

Comment: @LagrangeLover ${\mathbb Z}^2$ is a $2$-generated group and therefore so is ${\mathbb Z}^2/B$ for any subgroup $B$.

Comment: @LagrangeLover Re-read the first sentence of the answer. Any group of the form $\mathbb{Z}^2/B$ (for any $B$) is generated by the class of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. So any group which cannot be generated by $2$ elements *cannot* be of the form $\mathbb{Z}^2/B$ (for any $B$).

Comment: So can we say that $(1,0) + B$ and $(0,1) + B$ are generating $\mathbb Z^2 / B$?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I said.